# How to merge two dataframe in pyspark when one column is an array and another column is string?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

df1:

```
+---+------+
| id|  code|
+---+------+
|  1|[A, F]|
|  2|   [G]|
|  3|   [A]|
+---+------+
```

df2:

```
+--------+----+
|    col1|col2|
+--------+----+
|   Apple|   A|
|  Google|   G|
|Facebook|   F|
+--------+----+
```

I want the df3 should be like this by using the df1, and df2 columns :

```
+---+------+-----------------+
| id|  code|          changed|
+---+------+-----------------+
|  1|[A, F]|[Apple, Facebook]|
|  2|   [G]|         [Google]|
|  3|   [A]|          [Apple]|
+---+------+-----------------+
```

I know this can be archived if the code column is NOT an ARRAY. I don't know how to iterate the code array for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

res=(df1
     .select(f.col("id"), f.explode(f.col("code")).alias("code"))
     .join(df2, f.col("code")==df2.col2)
     .groupBy("id")
     .agg(f.collect_list(f.col("code")).alias("code"), f.collect_list(f.col("col1")).alias("changed"))
)
```